# Adsense ads not working in React Danderously set Innerhtml

Tags: reactjs, adsense, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have some text which I am tryint to show using Dangerously set Inner html.
The text is pretty long and changes based on user query, so I am using danderously set inner html to show it

I want to show Adsense ads in between these paragraphs, but that doesnt seem to be working.

in the text shown in dangerously set html, I have also included adsense script to show ads after every few paragraphs, and when inspected in chrome, I can see the script is at the right place too, but to doesnt show any ads.

There is a long fine called Chapter1.html which I am showing using dangerously set inner html, here is a small part of it:

```
<p>The hour’s just 9 o’clock.
    </p>
    <p>I should do laundry, clean and spend my time in the morning relaxing.
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-7107200228987000"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block; text-align:center;" data-ad-layout="in-article"
        data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7107200228987000" data-ad-slot="9551463795"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    <h3>Part 1</h3>
    <p>
        Inside Keyaki Mall in the forenoon, the atmosphere of Christmas Eve was in
        full swing.
    </p>
    <p>Inside the mall was decorated with even more gaudy ornaments than at the
        entrance.
    </p>
```

I cant find anything reliable on the internet, so I am here. any help is welcome.

Comment: Hey, could you add some example code to show what you've tried?

Comment: Added it in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Few notes.

1. Move `<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-7107200228987000" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` out of that snippet and put it in `<head>` of your site once.
2. I believe using `<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>` with innerHTML doesn't work. innerHTML doesn't evaluate inlined `<script>` tags. Instead you need to call `adsbygoogle.push({})` yourself after you set innerHTML.

Comment: 1 was already done by me
As for 2, I did that but it gave some other problems, so I ended up creating ad compoenent for react and then displaying ad in that component